# How to join a master table with 2 tables for getting count of master table primary id in 2 tables and with master table information in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join, codeigniter-query-builder

I have a master table its name is "user" table it contain all information of  user and there are two tables "business_list" and "classified_list".

I want to show all user information with total number of  business from  `business_list` table and total no of classifieds from `classified_list` 
table

**user** table

```
user_id    user_name     user_email         user_phone
-----------------------------------------------------     
001         Jose         jose@yahoo.in      457855654
002         Tom          tom@yahoo.in       5464644654
003         Nick         nick@yahoo.in      4545645644
004         Rose         rose@yahoo.in      554545441
```

**business_list**  table

```
bid        user_id      business_name
-----------------------------------------------
001        001          Construction business
002        003          Event business
003        001          Crane business
004        003          Furtinure business
005        004          Realestate business
```

**classified_list** table:

```
cid      user_id       classified_name
-------------------------------------------    
001      001           Roller classified
002      004           Home classified
003      003           Chair classified
004      004           Office Classified
005      002           Light decoration classified
```

I want to display information as

```
User Name   User Email         User Phone     No Of Business     No Of Classified
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Jose        jose@yahoo.in      457855654           2                   1
Tom         tom@yahoo.in       5464644654          0                   1
Nick        nick@yahoo.in      4545645644          2                   1
Rose        rose@yahoo.in      554545441           1                   2
```

So what is the mysql join query for getting this result, I am using php codeigniter 3.0 framework so it is nice, if anyone knows codeigniter
query for this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will give you the results you want. It joins the `user` table to a `UNION` of the `business_list` and `classified_list` tables and uses conditional aggregation to sum the number of businesses and classifieds associated with each user:

```
SELECT u.user_name AS `User Name`,
       u.user_email AS `User Email`,
       u.user_phone AS `User Phone`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN bc.type = 'business' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `No Of Business`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN bc.type = 'classified' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `No Of Classified`
FROM user u
JOIN (SELECT 'business' AS type, user_id 
      FROM business_list
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'classified' AS type, user_id
      FROM classified_list) bc
ON bc.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id;
```

Alternatively, you can use a `LEFT JOIN` to each table, `COUNT`ing `DISTINCT` values from each table:

```
SELECT u.user_name AS `User Name`,
       u.user_email AS `User Email`,
       u.user_phone AS `User Phone`,
       COUNT(DISTINCT b.bid) AS `No Of Business`,
       COUNT(DISTINCT c.cid) AS `No Of Classified`
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN business_list b ON b.user_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN classified_list c ON c.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

The output of both queries is the same:

```
User Name   User Email      User Phone  No Of Business  No Of Classified
Jose        jose@yahoo.in   457855654   2               1
Tom         tom@yahoo.in    5464644654  0               1
Nick        nick@yahoo.in   4545645644  2               1
Rose        rose@yahoo.in   554545441   1               2
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93b8c/5)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
select u.user_name, u.user_email, u.user_phone, count(distinct b.bid),
       count(distinct c.cid) from user_table u 
   left outer join business_list b 
       on  u.user_id=b.user_id 
   left outer join classified_list c 
       on c.user_id=u.user_id 
group by 
    u.user_name,u.user_email,u.user_phone
```

Comment: This is 100% working.but  i am using   codeigniter 3 frame work so i can't use coalesce()

Comment: Ah.. This by the way would produce the same result even without the coalesce because count would never return NULL. Updated my answer!!

Comment: count(distinct b.user_id) is required otherwise answer is false